# Restarting Heroku Delayed Job Workers from Ruby Script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

What is the best way, if possible, to restart Heroku (delayed_job) workers from within the Rails app itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You scale your workers using `heroku ps:scale worker=x`, right?

Scaling it down to 0 and again to original value will restart your workers.

You can do it programmatically using heroku ruby client, see an [example](http://verboselogging.com/2010/07/30/auto-scale-your-resque-workers-on-heroku) and (rather poor) [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/heroku/2.30.3/frames)

This code snipped may be helpful:

```
heroku = Heroku::Client.new(ENV['HEROKU_USER'], ENV['HEROKU_PASS'])
heroku.ps_scale(ENV['HEROKU_APP'], :type=>'worker', :qty=>0)
heroku.ps_scale(ENV['HEROKU_APP'], :type=>'worker', :qty=>1)
```

Comment: scaling down to 0 and then to original value worked for me.